# I'm having trouble boosting products using Solr in Hybris 6.4

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to boost the relevancy of products based on phrase searches such as "black shoes"

Searching for this phrase returns products that have black in the name, but not products that are shoes or are black. I have boosted color and item type to be higher than the name, but still no change in the search results.

Can someone advise how I can tune solr to return what I am looking for?

Comment: How are your fields set up. If you boost the color but that doesn't change the result, then the color field isn't contributing to the document's relevancy. When you run a query is the color field being searched? Is the field indexed?

Comment: How would I check this from the Solr admin?

Comment: You need to look in the `solrconfig.xml` for whether the fields are searched by the handler, and in `schema.xml` for if the field is indexed (assuming you're not using a managed schema, if so check `managed-schema`). To view those in the Solr admin, just choose the core/collection on the left dropdown and view "Files".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure legacyMode is disabled, you can disable it by running below Impex(change mySiteSolrIndexConfig with your SolrIndexConfig name).

```
$indexConfigName=mySiteSolrIndexConfig

INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexConfig ; name[unique=true] ; legacyMode ;  
                              ; $indexConfigName  ; false      ;
```

---

You can do the same thing from HMC/Platform

- Go to Facet search > Facet search config > open the result
- Open Solr configuration tab
- Find Indexer configuration and open it in the new window
- disable the Legacy Mode

Now you can boost Free text phrase of color SolrIndexedProperty

Comment: Yes legacy mode is disabled.